# Jumping from gud-interaction-buffer to code

Tags: gud, gdb

I'm trying to use GUD more as a front-end to GDB. I mostly work in the interaction buffer as I do normally on the command line. However when I come across a particular line in the code (through bt or frame) how can I jump to the code buffer? It seems such an obvious navigation but I can't figure out what command it is.